# HTML Form Submit pass array to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a simple HTML where you can click images. These images, whence clicked will moved to the Top Nav bar, I have IDs from this images and able to get each of them using jquery/javascript. I have this IDs set to an array variable.

My questions, is there a way to pass this to the Form then I issue a Submit so I can process the arrays. It is a 1D array with just IDs.

Comment: Provide something what u tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use hidden inputs:

```
<input type="hidden" name="image_ids[]" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="image_ids[]" value="2">
<input type="hidden" name="image_ids[]" value="3">
```

Just create a new hidden input for each image id, with the same name `image_ids[]`.

Note that when you append `[]` to the name of various input fields, these values are submitted as an array, in this case named `image_ids`.

Another solution is just to concatenate all the IDs with a comma: `"1,2,3,4,5"` and send it in just one hidden input field (instead of a bunch of hidden input fields), then in your server script (assuming you're using PHP) you can convert the string `"1,2,3,4,5"` to an array using something like: `$image_ids = explode(',', $_POST['image_ids']);`.

Good look.